# Merge Tow Table Without Mix The Rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

Thank in advance for helping

I have Tow table in sql server i want to union them without mix the Rows as the Flowing:

T1 IS

```
   ID    Name

   1     john
   2     Lol
```

T2 is

```
  ID    Name

  1     Normi
  2     CRI
```

iF I DO select LIKE THAT:
select Id,Name from T1 Union select Id,Name from T2
the result will be Like

```
 ID    Name
 1     john
 1     Normi
 2     Lol
 2     CRI
```

But for me i want the result Like

```
   ID    Name
   1     john
   2     Lol
   1     Normi
   2     CRI
```

Please Help thank you again

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.id, a.Name
FROM 
(select Id,Name, 1 as num from T1 Union select Id,Name, 2 as num from T2)a
ORDER BY a.num,a.Id
```

Comment: In this case `UNION ALL` would perhaps be preferable to `UNION`, as the latter implies `DISTINCT` and, consequently, unnecessary intermediate sorting, which is costly. (And the query planner might or might not optimise that out.)